# How to integrate Disqus comment counter into Bootstrap button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, disqus

I am trying to make Disqus comment counter link in Bootstrap button, but everything I tried was unsuccessful.
The idea is that the whole button should be link.
When I am trying to do like this:

```
<a href="page.html#disqus_thread">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button>
</a>
```

the Disqus just overwriting everything about Bootstrap button CSS and just leave naked link like "1" (I left just number in disqus settings).
When I am trying this way:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <a href="page.html#disqus_thread"></a>
</button>
```

the button appears, as well as comment counter link, but the button is not the link like if it was wrapped into `<a>` tag. So I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is not valid HTML. Try something like this:

```
<a href="page.html#disqus_thread" class="btn btn-default"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but it is still problem with adding text or "glyphicons" inside button. Counter link just overwriting it. But i think i found a solution by adding span with needed glyphicon class inside comment counter in Disqus settings.